# How to force a menuItemClick event based on the active tab index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs

I am struggling with the following problem: I have a Asp PageControl with two tabs (with indexes 0 and 1). The first tab actually represents a information panel with a few textboxes (with values populated from the db). The second one is a gridview with data taken from the db (the same data as in the first tab). On the top of the Page control I have a menu with insert, edit, delete, first, next, previous and last. For the first tab I have implemented its functionality. On the second one I want to do the following: if the user press Insert, I want the program to switch to the first tab and behave as the user has pressed the insert button on the first tab. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want the page to actually change tabs visually, or just invoke the insert call from the second tab?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [multiview control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx)  (exists in ToolBox when using ASP.net). this control gives you multi views, and you can see just One of them at a time, and you can switch between them. you set view1 to tab1 and view2 to tab2.

Comment: I have already done the content part .. and I can easily navigate trough it. My problem is how to force the menuItemClick event (when pressed from the second tab) to change the the active tab page and behave as it was invoked from the first tab.